# Questions about a very specific topic that are related to each other

Tags: discussion, questions, multiple-questions

Suppose I have many questions about a single, very specific topic. All these questions relate to each other, by which I mean that they give each other context.

Should I post all these questions at once, using a general title such as "I have a few questions about X" and putting all the questions in the question body?

Or should I post all the questions individually and provide links in the body to the other questions? This other approach has the problem that I have to wait 40 minutes in between each question (no, I am not trying to find loopholes in the site's rules, the questions really are that interconnected to each other).

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure none of your questions have answers. It's unlikely on most sites that that is the case. It's important to search first and indicate in the question why answers to similar questions don't help you (assuming you find any).

If you ask multiple questions at once your question is likely to be closed as too broad. This is a universal close reason i.e. it exists on all sites.

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

In addition its unlikely that lots of other people would need or want to solve all of your questions, it's more likely that they would be stuck on only one point. Why should you make them read through a lot of information they don't need or want and then tease out only the bit of the answer that's appropriate.

Furthermore if you get an answer to your first question, what's to say that you won't be able to do more of your own research now that you know better what to look for. That might cut down or change the other questions you need to ask.